# X11 Forwarding Works On One Host, "Can't Open Display" On Other [PUTTY/XMING]

Tags: linux, putty, x11

I have two identical servers, server A and server B. If I connect to server A in Putty and enable X11 forwarding in the settings (running XMING on my PC), everything works fine. I can run all the test commands like 'xeyes' or 'xclock' and they work fine too.

However doing the exact same thing on server B results in a

```
Error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0
```

doing

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

on both servers returns the same (localhost:10.0) and both servers are on the same network so the firewall rules are identical (though I'm not sure this is relevant as the commands should go through SSH)

What should I try next to get X11 working on server B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work in the end. In /etc/hosts there were the lines

```
1.2.3.4   server.lan
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Reversing those lines so the localhost line was first stopped the errors

Answer (score 0):

Probably the server B does not have **X11Forwarding** enabled in /etc/ssh/sshd_config. Make sure it says yes (and the line is not commented), restart sshd, you should be all set.

Comment: X11Forwarding is enabled in sshd_config, X11 has worked on this server before but it was a while ago I think